# Why do processes started from a bash script used as monit service persist after the script terminates?

Tags: linux, bash, process, fork, monit

I have a bash script that I've set up as a monit service. The script ends with a long-running call to `tail` that pipes its output to `nc` to be sent to an external server.

The issue I'm having is that when I stop the service using monit, the process for the bash script dies, but the process for the `tail` call made by that script persists. I've showed an example of this behavior below.

```
$ sudo monit start service
$ ps aux | grep -E 'service|tail'
root     26215  0.0  0.0  17876   464 ?        S    18:31   0:00 /bin/bash -x /path/to/service.sh &>/var/log/service.log
root     26216  0.0  0.0   4344   352 ?        S    18:31   0:00 tail -q -n 0 -f /var/log/app.log /var/log/db.log /var/log/mail.log
root     26217  0.0  0.1  20736  1060 ?        S    18:31   0:00 nc server.foo.com 1234
$ sudo cat /var/run/service.pid
26215
$ sudo monit stop service
$ ps aux | grep -E 'service|tail'
root     26216  0.0  0.0   4344   352 ?        S    18:31   0:00 tail -q -n 0 -f /var/log/app.log /var/log/db.log /var/log/mail.log
root     26217  0.0  0.1  20736  1060 ?        S    18:31   0:00 nc server.foo.com 1234
```

I've tried making the `tail` call in a few different ways:

1) in the foreground, outputting the bash script PID to the PID file

```
echo "$$" > $PID_FILE
tail -q -n 0 -f $args | nc server.foo.com 1234
```

2) in the background without using a subshell, outputting what should be the last backgrounded process PID to the PID file

```
{ tail -q -n 0 -f $args | nc server.foo.com 1234; } &
echo "$!" > $PID_FILE
```

3) in the background using a subshell, outputting what should be the subshell PID to the PID file

```
( echo $BASHPID > $PID_FILE; tail -q -n 0 -f $args | nc server.foo.com 1234 ) &
```

Oddly, all these approaches appear to result in the behavior shown above: the bash script PID is always used, the bash script process terminates when monit stops the service, the `tail` process does not.

I want to know why this happens and how to kill off any processes invoked by the bash script when the associated service is terminated by monit.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
bash -c "tail -q -n 0 -f $args | nc server.foo.com 1234"
```

Comment: No difference in behavior, I'm afraid.

Comment: The crux of the issue is that something seems to be disassociating the script monit runs and processes spawned by that script as a result of invoking commands, such that those processes persist even after monit kills the script process when the service is stopped. I'm still not sure why or how.